# What is difference between Wildcard SSL and just SSL?

Tags: security-certificate

What is difference between Wildcard SSL and just normal SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a very *high-level*, a "Wildcard" SSL certificate would allow `<any-subdomain>.example.com`. Whereas a "normal" SSL cert would be limited to just a single host. eg. `example.com` or `my-subdomain.example.com`, but not both.

However, many "normal" SSL certs do cover both the apex and `www` subdomains these days. ie. `example.com` *and* `www.example.com` - since this is a very common requirement.

Or were you after a deeper explanation?

Comment: Consider that a "normal" cert can act as a Wildcard for up to 500 tertiary subdomains by adding them into the SAN field of the certificate.

Comment: Hey downvoter, please consider leaving a comment... otherwise it doesn't help anyone.